# Comparing two characters using the & operator

Tags: c#

I am comparing the following two characters with &:
'\u0874'
'a'

and I get   `  as output.
I know that 'a' in binary is 01000001
and '\u0874' in binary is(UTF-8 encoding)  11100000:10100001:10110100

How exactly does the & operator work here?

```
        char comp58 = 'a';
        char comp96 ='\u0874';
        Console.WriteLine(comp96&=comp58);
```

Comment: You're using the `&=` operator, not the `&` operator.

Comment: A bitwise AND is not a comparison. What are you trying to do?

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I just formulated the question differently

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly, note what what you're actually doing is anding `comp96` with `comp58` and assigning the result to `comp96` by using the `&=` operator. Because of this, you are outputting a character rather than an integer.

Secondly, note that the characters in C# are using UTF16.

Thirdly, note that the UTF16 code for `a` is actually `00000000 01100001`.

So the AND you're actually performing is:

```
00000000 01100001 'a'
00001000 01110100 '\u0874'
-----------------
00000000 01100000 Result
```

And `00000000 01100000` is the UTF16 code for "`" (grave/accent) which is what you're seeing as the output.

Note that if you changed your code to:

```
Console.WriteLine(comp96 & comp58);
```

the output would be `96` because now you would be outputting the result of ANDing two chars, which will be an integer.

Comment: Thank you, so does the console output in utf-16 by default?

Comment: No, but you can do `Console.OutputEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;` to enable UTF encoding support.

Comment: To clarify: All characters with codes less than 128 decimal are the same in UTF8 and ASCII, so all such characters will be displayed in a console correctly regardless of whether you set the output encoding to Unicode.